# Subview of UITableViewCell occasionally disappears

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass which has a property called entryView, in place of the read-only cell.contentView. I thought I was using the table view correctly - remembering that the cells get re-used for every entry, and everything needs to be added every time. Occasionally when scrolling however, the entryView will disappear on a cell. The cell will still be there, but the entryView appears to be removed from superview. Here's my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    JTimelineCell *cell = (JTimelineCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[JTimelineCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    JTimelineCellContentView *contentView;

    Entry *entry = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([self.cellContentCache objectForKey:entry.entryID]) {
        contentView = [self.cellContentCache objectForKey:entry.entryID];

        contentView.frame = cell.bounds;
        [contentView setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    else {

        contentView = [[JTimelineCellContentView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];


        [self.cellContentCache setObject:contentView forKey:entry.entryID];

        contentView.time = [NSDate timeStringForTime:entry.creationDate];

        contentView.message = entry.message;

        [cell setNeedsDisplay];
}

    [cell.entryView removeFromSuperview];
    cell.entryView = contentView;

    [cell addSubview:cell.entryView];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you posted something similar in a different question. You cannot cache the contentView of a cell. You CAN cache images, strings, numbers, values etc - but in the end, when you get a cell, you need to retrieve the elements that will DISPLAY those values, and then set their values to do so. So you can cache images, strings, CGRects, etc - and then when asked to populate a cell, you can look at your cache, and if valid then get the values you have cached. If the cache is not set, then you need to create them from scratch.

Every time you get a cell for a particular section/row, its different. It maybe have old values in it, or it may be new. You need to set each GUI element for each item. One way to make it easy to find those elements is give each a unique tag, so you can use [cell.contentView viewForTag:xxx] to get the item, then set it.

Comment: So here's what I think i'm doing.. Initing my UIView subclass. Adding my properties to it. Putting it in a cache. Then adding it to my cell. Then later on, getting it from the cache, and putting it in a cell again. It's only ever removed from superview. It's not nil'd. Why is it a problem?

Comment: Every cell is unique. The contentView is a UIView, its unique to the cell. Each time you get a cell for a section/row, its unique. You cannot just mess with the view. You are confusing the "view" in MVC with the "model", which is the information. The whole idea of the cell recycling is that each cell comes with its views defined - either newly created or already used. You need to SET the objects/values NEEDED by those views to the DATA they need. Forget trying to cache GUI elements, and think caching DATA.

Comment: So could I instead create an NSObject subclass, with all my pieces of data as properties, and then give that to the custom contentview, as a property of it?

Comment: I do it with a dictionary - each object has a key, so when you need to populate a cell you get the proper dictionary, the go through it setting each GUI element with the value you pull out of the dictionary using some key, You can simplify this by setting each GUI element's tags with the value you use in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Did you using **heightForRowAtIndexPath** method if yes then increase its height resolved problem in my case i was trying similar fix and its driving me crazy.

Comment: thank you!  At first I thought this answer was "stackoverflow spam" because it's a one liner, and you had this in other similar entries (losing data in custom uitableviewcells when scrolling), but it worked, specifically setting the height: `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
{return 145.0f;}`.  Spent all night debugging/trying other solutions!  Thanks again.